# Webpack is Compiling unwanted modules

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have a Node.js application that is compiled with webpack.  After compiling my application and running it I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'oracledb'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at t.(anonymous function).i (C:\Users\xxx\Documents\xxx\web-test-nodejs\dist\api\bundled.js:1:400)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\Documents\xxx\web-test-nodejs\dist\api\bundled.js:1:1982)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\Documents\xxx\web-test-nodejs\index.js:19:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
```

I am not utilizing oracledb and have explicitly excluded it in my webpack config file (included below).  I am using mysql with knex, and I believe that knex is the cause of this error.  How can I get rid of this error?

```
module.exports = [{
    entry: [
        './src/api/index.js',
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: externalNodeModules,
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: externalNodeModules,
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                enforce: 'pre',
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: externalNodeModules,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['env'],
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(html)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options: {
                        attrs: [':data-src'],
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    node: {
        __dirname: true,
    },
    target: 'node',
    externals: {
        'sqlite3': 'sqlite3',
        'mariasql': 'mariasql',
        'mssql': 'mssql',
        'mysql2': 'mysql2',
        'oracle': 'oracle',
        'strong-oracle': 'strong-oracle',
        'oracledb': 'oracledb',
        'pg': 'pg',
        'pg-query-stream': 'pg-query-stream',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'api'),
        filename: 'bundled.js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            'node_modules',
            'src/node_modules',
            'src',
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            debug: false,
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            beautify: false,
            mangle: {
                screw_ie8: true,
                keep_fnames: true,
            },
            compress: {
                screw_ie8: true,
            },
            comments: false,
        }),
    ],
}, {
    entry: {
        'index': './src/entry/app.js',
        '404': './src/entry/404.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [
                    externalNodeModules,
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/static/js/third_party'),
                ],
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                enforce: 'pre',
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: externalNodeModules,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['env'],
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: externalNodeModules,
                use: extractCSS.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader',
                }),
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                exclude: externalNodeModules,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=30000&name=font/[name].[ext]',

            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|ico)$/,
                exclude: externalNodeModules,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]',
            },
        ],
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: '/',
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'web', 'static'),
        filename: 'js/[name].js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            debug: false,
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            beautify: false,
            mangle: {
                screw_ie8: true,
                keep_fnames: true,
            },
            compress: {
                screw_ie8: true,
            },
            comments: false,
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        extractCSS,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jquery': 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.$': 'jquery',
            'window.jquery': 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
                from: 'views/**/*.pug',
                context: 'src/',
                to: '..',
            },
            {
                from: 'img/profile/**/*.{jpg,gif,png}',
                context: 'src/static/',
            },
        ]),
    ],
}];
```

**EDIT**

This error is thrown after building the application when running `node index.js`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to install one of the modules here after installing knex:

http://knexjs.org/#Installation-node

So first:

```
npm install knex --save
```

then:

```
npm install mysql --save
```

I expect installing mysql will prevent it looking for oracledb

Also make sure you specify your client as mysql:

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    user : 'your_database_user',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test'
  }
});
```

Also remove references to Oracledb in your webpack config.